# SQL,SSRS, SQL SERVER,

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a transaction based table in SQL from which I am creating an SSRS report. I have a filter based on transaction dates, like below:

```
Label 7-13 value 1
Label 14-28 value 2
Label 7-28 value 3
```

If the user selects `1` then I need to show all the transactions which happen between 7-13 days from today. And same for others. Please advise me how I do this at the query level.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that includes sample data:

```
declare @value int
select @value = 1

;with cte as
(
    select cast(getdate() as date) dt
    union all
    select dateadd(day, -1, dt)
    from cte
    where dt > getdate() - 30
)
select * 
from cte
where (@value = 1 and dt between DATEADD(day, -13, cast(getdate() as date)) and DATEADD(day, -7, cast(getdate() as date)))
or (@value = 2 and dt between DATEADD(day, -28, cast(getdate() as date)) and DATEADD(day, -14, cast(getdate() as date)))
or (@value = 3 and dt between DATEADD(day, -28, cast(getdate() as date)) and DATEADD(day, -7, cast(getdate() as date)))
```

The key is in the where clause:

```
WHERE (@value = 1 AND [do this if @value = 1])
OR (@value = 2 AND [do this if @value = 2])
etc.
```